# Can I run a application with alsa inside the android emulator?

Tags: android, image, audio, android-emulator, alsa

I'm making my own image to run on the Android Emulator. Within this image I have a application that wants to use alsa for sound. Is this possible withing the Android Emulator?

With adb push I send over aplay. And with aplay -l I get a message that there are no sound devices available.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Yes but you will not get proper output as emulator is slow with alsa so its better if you test it with an android phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely YES  u can run in emulator

check using

adb shell logcat | grep alsa

Comment: Updated my question. I would also like to know how.

Answer (score 2):

There is no ALSA in the Android emulator. It uses its own /dev/eac pseudo device → http://www.mail-archive.com/android-porting@googlegroups.com/msg04355.html